# Three phase power generation

Tags: power

Three is the minimum number of phases determined to generate and transmit power in the most cost effective manner and it is also helps to built self starting motors.

Throughout the history of power technology, various systems were invented and tested from DC, various combinations of polyphase systems and frequencies. Diminishing benefits of more than three phases for polyphase systems is well understood and suddenly at some point of history THREE is determined to be the best solution.

My question is who is the individual or group of people finalized the decision? Nikola Tesla himself or some regulatory body?

Comment: I don't know the formal answer (although I'm sure that Garglabet does) BUT it was probably not "some point in history)(If it was it would be easily enough identified) but "market forces building an "edifice" that was not liable to be overturned. 3 phases give you reasonably constant energy delivery across one cycle, not too too much implementation infrastructure compared with the two wires of DC or 1 phase AC and much less than 5 phase. $ and practicality lead and the industry follows. ...

Comment: Not an EE design question.

Comment: Andy Aka, its more like historical part of EE design and certainly not agricultural question. If those in EE don't know the answer I supposed no body else know. So this is the best place to get to the answer.

Comment: I agree that the historical part of EE design contributes something to EE design in general. However, this may be too involved for the question and answer format. A better answer may be found by searching and finding sites like this: http://ethw.org/Edison's_Electric_Light_and_Power_System

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short:

3 phases give you reasonably constant energy delivery across one cycle, not too too much implementation infrastructure compared with the two wires of DC or 1 phase AC and much less than 5 phase. $ and practicality lead and the industry follows.

---

Longer:

I don't know the formal answer (although I'm sure that Garglabet does) BUT it was probably not "some point in history (and if it was it would be easily enough identified)), but more likely to be "market forces building an "edifice" that was not liable to be overturned.

DC and 1 phase AC require two conductors.
For a reasonably balanced feed, 3 phase requires 3 conductors for transmission over distance. Neutral is something you can derive remotely as required.  3 phase gives you a true rotating field for rotary machines - induction motors and others) unlike 1 phase.
Assuming odd number of phases are liable to be selected for a range of reasons, 5 phase requires 5 wires. And 5 sets of insulators per location. And extra hassles with transformer design. For minimal gains.
Throw in $ and practicality and  3 phase looks likely to be the winner that it proved to be.

Answer (score 3):

Think about the way things usually progress. They often start simple. Edison started with DC and two wires. Early on, someone figured out that two DC generators could be connected together and share a common wire between them. Thus two 110 volt DC circuits could be provided. If the two circuits had approximately equal loads, the common wire would carry less than either of other two. There is a good chance that a US patent can be found for the three-wire DC system.

When AC transmission systems began to be developed, the developer's had the benefit of the three-wire DC system. People figured out two-phase and three-phase systems. Other systems may have been thought about, but the lack of any advantage was probably realized without much testing or any building of such systems. At various times, some ideas must have been re-visited. The idea of phase multiplication was developed and used in special situations.

Comment: So everyone seems to agree about the choice and implemented 3 phase systems without acknowledging the originator and paying some royalty or anything like that?

Comment: Patents are granted only for a limited time, 17 years n the USA currently. The history of early disputes, agreements and patents on improvements can be found and will tell more of the story. Developments in other countries are an important part of the story also.